# reCAPTCHA , как разместить несколько блоков на одной странице

Tags: recaptcha

Имеется авторизация/регистрация на одной странице.

Но почему-то я не могу добавить сразу две капчи, одна не работает.

Есть ли обход по этому?

Или же делать её вывод после нажатия на кнопку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте два тега с разными id и инициализируйте recaptcha отдельно для каждого из них.

**html:**

```
<div id="recaptcha1"></div>
<div id="recaptcha2"></div>
```

**javascript:**

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
<script>
        var onloadCallback = function() {
            grecaptcha.render('recaptcha1', {
                'sitekey' : 'yourkey'
            });
            grecaptcha.render('recaptcha2', {
                'sitekey' : 'yourkey'
            });
        };
</script>
```

Comment: Отлично, спасибо большое!! Всё помогло.

Comment: отрисовались элементы, но почему-то, данные не приходят мне в .js файл .
`var Captcha = grecaptcha.getResponse();` всегда null , то есть данные вообще не приходят ни в какую..
Как можно решить проблему?
@Pyramidhead

Comment: @MoloF, не видя код, ничего сказать не могу. Но предположу, что в `grecaptcha.getResponse()` в скобках нужно указать id капчи. Например, `grecaptcha.getResponse('recaptcha1')`.

Comment: Слишком много мороки, пожалуй лучше я сделаю одну общую капчу и всё.
Там слишком накладно, что-то указывать и везде прописывать.

Можно тогда вопрос не по теме, как сменить тему у рекапчи на dark?
@Pyramidhead
Я знаю что можно прописать её в `render` , а по другому никак?

Comment: На самом деле, это только кажется муторным. Если обрабатываете формы в js, то в этих обработчиках и проверяйте определённые капчи. Тему можно задать ещё в атрибуте элемента `data-theme="dark"`.

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56515261/recapcha-v3-doesnt-work-on-page-with-multiple-forms

```
grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    grecaptcha.execute();
    grecaptcha
        .execute('key', {
            action: "contact"
        })
        .then(function(token) {
            document
                .querySelectorAll(".g-recaptcha-response")
                .forEach(elem => (elem.value = token))
            ;
        });
});
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
<script>    
    var onloadCallback = function() {
                var divcaptcha = document.getElementsByClassName('g-recaptcha');
                for (var i = 0; i < divcaptcha.length; i++) {
                  grecaptcha.render(divcaptcha[i], {
                    'sitekey': 'your sitekey'
                  });
                }
              };
</script>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".g-recaptcha").each(function( element ) {
let recaptcha_ok = false;    
let is_recaptcha_visible = ($(this).data('size') !== 'invisible');
let the_form = $(this).closest("form");
let the_button = $(the_form).find('input[type="submit"]');
  
if (!the_button.length) {
  the_button = $(the_form).find(':button');
}

// visible
if (the_button.length && is_recaptcha_visible) {
  the_button.prop("disabled", true);
  the_button.css("opacity", 0.5);
}

// Колбеки к рекапчам и сюда просто добавляете колбэки для получения ответа
window.form_button_header = function () {
  if (!$('.sub_header_but').length) return;
  $('.sub_header_but').prop("disabled", false);
  $('.sub_header_but').css( "opacity", 1 );
};
window.form_button_prefoot = function () {
  if (!$('.sub_prefoot_but').length) return;
  $('.sub_prefoot_but').prop("disabled", false);
  $('.sub_prefoot_but').css( "opacity", 1 );
};


// invisible
if (!is_recaptcha_visible) {
  $(the_button).on('click', function (event) {
    if (recaptcha_ok) return;
    event.preventDefault();
    grecaptcha.execute();
  });
}

window.now_submit_the_form = function () {
  recaptcha_ok = true;
  //$(the_button).click(); // this is only way to submit a form that contains "submit" inputs
  $(the_button).trigger('click'); // this is only way to submit a form that contains "submit" inputs
};})
```

Сама Форма

```
<form id="line-form" class="line-wrap">
    <input type="tel" name="Телефон" placeholder="Введите телефон" required>
    <div class="g-recaptcha line-rec" data-sitekey="Ваш ключь" data-callback="form_button_header"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="" class="sub_header_but"> </form>
```

Вторая форма

```
<form id="line-form2" class="line-wrap">
    <input type="tel" name="Телефон" placeholder="Введите телефон" required>
    <div class="g-recaptcha line-rec" data-sitekey="Ваш ключь" data-callback="form_button_prefoot "></div>
    <input type="submit" value="" class="sub_prefoot_but"> </form>
```